# Powershell Get-Acl on UNC paths with spaces

Tags: powershell, acl, unc

I am trying to check ACLs on UNC paths via the `Get-Acl` cmdlet.

The below works fine when browsing the local filesystem or on a UNC path without spaces.

```
$ou = 'OU=Security Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=local'

$basepath =  '\\mydomain\dfsroot'

$filter = '*501*'

Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $ou -Filter { Name -like $filter } | % {
    $principle = $_.samAccountName
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $basepath -Recurse | % {
        $path = $_.FullName
        ($path | Get-Acl).Access.IdentityReference | % { if ( $_.Value -match $principle ) { Write-Host "$principle has rights to $path" }}
    }
}
```

On UNC paths with spaces I get a "FileNotFoundException":

> Get-Acl : \local501\dfsroot\docs\Accounting\Bankruptcy Files\NOTICE TO MEMBERSHIP RE-CHAPTER 11.pdf
>      At C:\Users\administrator.LOCAL501\Documents\IT Support Guys - (855) 4 IT GUYS\Files\find_paths_by_principle.ps1:11 char:18
>      +         ($path | Get-Acl).Access.IdentityReference | % { if ( $_.Valu ...
>      +                  ~~~~~~~
>          + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Acl],FileNotFoundException
>          + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand

Can somebody help me understand what's going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So your code is a little needlessly complicated.  Here's a script that's easier to understand the flow and shouldn't error out on spaces:

```
If (-not (Test-Path -Path DFS:\))
{ New-PSDrive -Name DFS -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\mydomain\dfsroot }

$OU         = 'OU=Security Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=local'
$Filter     = '*501*'
$Principles = (Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $OU -Filter {Name -like $Filter}).samAccountName
$Collection = @()

ForEach ($Path in (Get-ChildItem -Path DFS:\ -Recurse -ErrorVariable +CustomERR))
{
    ## Using an array literal so items don't end up appended to one giant hashtable
    $Collection += @(
        @{ Path = $Path.FullName
           Acl  = (Get-Acl -Path $Path.FullName).Access.IdentityReference.Value
         }
    )
}

ForEach ($Principle in $Principles)
{
    ForEach ($Item in $Collection)
    {
        If ($Item.Acl -contains $Principle)
        {
            Write-Host "'$Principle' has rights to '$($Item.Path)'"
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: made some optimizations

Comment: That command gives me the below:

Get-ChildItem : Could not find a part of the path '\\mydomain\dfsroot\demo\path'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem '\\mydomain\dfsroot' -Recurse
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (\\mydomain\dfsr...mo\path:String) [Get-ChildItem], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: @ChristianGerlach Does `\\mydomain\dfsroot\demo\path` have spaces?  That's a very strange error to see so early in execution.

Comment: Yes, it does.

I agree it is strange.

Comment: @ChristianGerlach OK, so I have a new suggestion I'm going to edit into my answer

Comment: @ChristianGerlach Updated

Comment: Still getting the same error when using the PSDrive.
It's just the Get-ChildItem command failing (commented out the rest):
Get-ChildItem -Path DFS:\ -Recurse

Comment: @ChristianGerlach Is the DFS hosted on a linux server? are you sure the characters are spaces and not something else?

Comment: Nope, this is Windows.

Just spaces.

Comment: @ChristianGerlach I changed the GCI call, try it with the modification, then check out the `$CustomERR` array for why things are failing.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore this!
My DFS share is full of corruption!
Filenames just happened to be ones with spaces.
Good news!